# Need help identifying capacitor values from monitor PCB

Tags: capacitor, identification, repair, monitor

I am trying to replace the SMD electrolytic capacitors from an LG E2442 but I am getting confused in regards to determining the correct values. I am trying to determine three different cspacitors types as shown in the images below.

I can somewhat determine some of the values of the first one but get really confused about the others.

[image]
For the first Capacitor I believe:

100v = 100 Volts

27 = Capacitance but I am unsure what the symbol before and after it is therefore I don't know how that is modifying/multiplying the value

J = 5% Tolerance

33 = ???

[image]

[image]

Here is an image of the PCB with the capacitors in red circle in case it helps.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of those, the top number is a date code. Below that, the capacitance, followed by the voltage.

So 33uF/100V (that one looks bulged and is probably bad)
68uF/35V, 100uF/16V

The character following the capacitance is probably a series code, not a tolerance.

Be sure to match the polarity (black partial circle).